# SQLITE in Python not creating tables but creates database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to connect to SQLITE database and it would seem that the code does create the database, but however it does not create the tables nor does it insert anything in them (most probably because they were never created)
I have SQLite DB Browser and in it I open the database but lack any tables or anything at all. Also I see my database in the folder next to my project.

I have the following code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("dfg.db")
c = conn.cursor()

def create_tabe():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabl(city TEXT, temp REAL)')

def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO tabl VALUES ('dasfsd', 32434)")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Try to actually call your `create_tabe()` and `data_entry()` methods ;)

Comment: Yes I am stupid, i forgot that however no that I did they are still not being created.

Comment: Nope, bever mind fixed it and thank you Yaroslav